# Intermittent NullReferenceException in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am seeing an intermittent issue that we cannot reliably reproduce in ASP.NET Identity (MVC 5.2.3).

The top of the stack trace suggests the issue is occurring on retrieving the password hash from the database:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at Portal.Web.Identity.IdentityStorageContext.<>c.<get_PasswordHash>b__6_0()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

SQL server isn't logging any errors. Trying the action again succeeds. We have noticed it occuring on both live and pre-prod.

IdentityStorageContext.cs extract:

```
public Task<string> PasswordHash
{
     get { return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => identityUser.PasswordHash); }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `Portal.Web.Identity.IdentityStorageContext` yours?

Comment: Yes, I've added the code above

Comment: I guess `identityUser` is null then.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman - I know what a null reference is! I was looking for ideas on how to debug an intermittent issue.

Comment: Use exception handling together with a logging framework. Nothing else we can make from this. Sorry.